# How do you swap values in lua tables?

Tags: lua

How would you swap a value in a table and exchange it for a different one? for example:

```
local TestTable = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
local SwappedTestTable = TestTable:Swap(2, 4)
for i, v in pairs(TestTable) do
    print(v)
end

-- Output = 1, 4, 3, 2, 5
```

This is what I've tried and it failed horrendously.

```
local TestTable = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

function Swap(Table, Pos1, Pos2)
    local Table = Table
    local Item1 = Table[Pos1]
    local Item2 = Table[Pos2]
    
    table.remove(Table, Pos1)
    table.insert(Table, Pos2, Item1)
    
    table.remove(Table, Pos2)
    table.insert(Table, Pos1, Item2)
    
    return Table
end

for _, v in pairs(Swap(TestTable, 2, 4)) do
    print(v)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is what I've tried and it failed horrendously.

An interesting solution, but plagued by major issues:

1. It fails to deal with the index shifts the `table.insert` and `table.remove` calls cause, causing later `table.insert` and `table.remove` calls to operate on the wrong indices (this could be fixed though)
2. It takes **linear time** (due to the aforementioned index shifts), which is unacceptable for such a basic operation.
3. It is overly complex.

> How would you swap a value in a table and exchange it for a different one?

I would simply get the two values and set them to the respective "other" index, swapping the values in constant time:

```lua
function Swap(Table, Pos1, Pos2)
    local tmp = Table[Pos1]
    Table[Pos1] = Table[Pos2]
    Table[Pos2] = tmp
    return Table
end
```

Lua allows you to write this even more concise using "multiple assignments":

```lua
function Swap(Table, Pos1, Pos2)
    Table[Pos1], Table[Pos2] = Table[Pos2], Table[Pos1]
    return Table
end
```

(at which point the `Swap` function becomes superfluous, as it is hardly any shorter or more concise than writing down the assignment each time)

Notes:

1. If you want to be able to use the `Swap` function in an OOP fashion (`Table:Swap(i, j)`), you'll have to assign a metatable. `local metatable = {__index = {Swap = Swap}}; setmetatable(Table, metatable)` will work for this.
2. Why does the `Swap` function return the `Table`? This is only useful for some syntactic sugar (chaining, f.E. with `pairs` as in your example) and might be unexpected in a language that distinguishes statements and expressions.
3. Again, I would probably not use a function for this (especially considering the code necessary to `require` the function or the global namespace pollution you otherwise need to make it available), but instead **simply use the assignments** `Table[i], Table[j] = Table[j], Table[i]`.
4. Your naming convention (which I've sticked to in this post) is somewhat irritating; `UpperCamelCase` is usually used for class & metatable names in Lua rather than functions and (table) variables.